# Crystal Report how to remove a line with "string"

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

[image]

Is it possible to just display **second line of "SST**" only using crystal report to extract the value from that field.

My coding is below:

using Mid

```
mid({Invoice.InvGSTSumCode},4)
```

using Carriage return

```
Trim(split({Invoice.InvGSTSumCode},chr(13))[2])
```

Result come out is not what i want, it give me an extra one line space

[image]

Comment: are there only two values for that column in database?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably also a line feed character -- Chr(10) -- hiding in there. 
So use something like: `split({Invoice.InvGSTSumCode},chr(10) + chr(13))[2]`